# unittest.mock: Como posso mocar datetime.datetime.now com chamadas diferentes no mesmo metodo?

Tags: python-3.x, mock

Como posso proceder com um teste mock em datetime.datetime.now com chamadas diferentes no mesmo metodo?

Em meus teste é retornado a data corrente.

Segue um exemplo do código, para facilitar a ajuda. Desde já grato.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def metodo():
    return dt.today().strftime('%Y'), dt.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X %z')


def test_metodo(self):
    expected = ('2018', "2018-12-14 12:34:56")
    mock_date = Mock(spec=mypackage.metodo)
    today.side_effect=list(expected)
    self.assertIsNotNone(metodo())
    self.assertEqual(expected, metodo())
```

Answer (score 0):

Obtive sucesso com este:

```
@patch('mypackage.dt')
def test_metodo(self, mock_date):
    expected = ('2018', "2018-12-14 12:34:56")
    mock_date.today.return_value = mypackage.dt(2018, 12, 14, 12, 34, 56)
    mock_date.today.return_value.strftime.side_effect = list(expected)
    self.assertIsNotNone(metodo())
    self.assertEqual(expected, metodo())
```